# mapping file not found error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I tried to write a simple programm with hibernate and MySQL but I get this error:

```
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 06, 2013 3:51:37 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : /hibernate-contact.hbm.xml
resource: /hibernate-contact.hbm.xml not found
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Untersuchungsraum.Contact" table="contact"/>
  <id column="firstname" type="string" >
      <generator class="native">
      </generator>
  </id>
  <property name="firstname">
      <column name="firstname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="lastnamename">
      <column name="lastname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="email">
      <column name="email"></column>
  </property>


 ...
```

and it is my XML configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rcf?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="/hibernate-contact.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

an my project looks like this:
[image]

why I do get this problem and hw can I solve it?

**EDIT**
my `hbm.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Untersuchungsraum.Contact" table="contact">
  <property name="firstname">
      <column name="Firstname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="lastname">
      <column name="lastname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="email">
      <column name="email"></column>
  </property>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

and my POJO Class:

```
package Untersuchungsraum;
public class Contact {
    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
```

}

Comment: Make your life simple and put it in some package.

Comment: I did it, but the error remains

Comment: Remove slash and try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `.xml` and `.hbm.xml` in the `src` folder, instead of this package.

Comment: I did it but also I have the problem: `Aug 06, 2013 4:15:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 06, 2013 4:15:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Comment: Then put both `.xml` and `.hbm.xml` outside package, means directly in `src` folder.

Comment: now I have another error: `SEVERE: Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(33) The content of element type "hibernate-mapping" must match "(meta*,typedef*,import*,(class|subclass|joined-subclass|union-subclass)*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*,filter-def*,database-object*)".
**Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate-contact.hbm.xml**`

Comment: Now your `.hbm.xml` is detected, but it have grammatical errors. Refer to some example, and write it again.

Comment: remove `/` from `<class name="Untersuchungsraum.Contact" table="contact"/>` and close `</class>` at end of class definition

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited it but still have this error: **Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate-contact.hbm.xml**

Comment: post your `.hbm.xml` again.

Comment: There must me a `<id>` which is primary key of your table. And also have to mention `type` of each column. Refer [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html)